# VBA Goal Seek in Excel on different cells every time

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I am making an Excel Sheet for investing.

I have the following columns:

- A showing the year (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, etc.)
- B showing the yearly cost
- C showing the yearly income
- D showing the total cost/income (B minus C) for the year
- E showing the overall income / loss

Now...

I want to have an automatic Goal Seek when I click a button. I want it to Goal Seek the LAST CELL WITH A NUMBER IN IT. Meaning, if I have an investing with 10 years, it should E10. If it has 5 years, E5 etc.

I can't seem to find anything on this subject. I want it to Goal Seek the LAST CELL WITH A NUMBER to the value 0.

How can I do this in a VBA routine?

By the way, I have a cell that shows me the name of the LAST CELL WITH A NUMBER. It says like "E3" if it's E3.

Comment: Is there anything in the cells below that "Last cell with a number", like a formula or text? Is it the last cell with a number specifically, or the last cell with ANY data?

Comment: Below there is a formula and it displays BLANK ("")

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do:

```
Sub GoalSeek()
    Const csOverallSt As String = "E1"
    Const csChangeCol As String = "C"
    Const ciGoal As Integer = 0

    Dim rngCheck As Range

    Set rngCheck = Range(csOverallSt)
    Do While rngCheck.Offset(1, 0).Value <> ""
        Set rngCheck = rngCheck.Offset(1)
    Loop

    rngCheck.GoalSeek goal:=ciGoal, changingcell:=Range(csChangeCol & rngCheck.Row)
End Sub
```

The constant `csOverallSt` defines the first cell you want to check for a blank - that way you don't need the extra cell defining which is the first blank cell. The constant `csChangeCol` defines which column contains the value you want the goal seek process to change. The constant `ciGoal` defines what value the Goal Seek should look for. The variable `rngCheck` defines a range of cells or, as we're using it here, a single cell.

The procedure starts by assigning `rngCheck` to match whichever cell you've defined in `csOverallSt`. It then checks to see if the cell below `rngCheck` is blank; if it is not, it moves `rngCheck` down by one row, and checks again. It will continue doing this until it finds a blank cell.

When it finds the blank cell, it will perform a goal seek, trying to set the value in `rngCheck` to the value you defined in `ciGoal` by changing the value in the column defined in `csChangeCol` and the same row as `rngCheck`.